# Client host blocked - JavaMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am unable to send a mail through JavaMail API 
this is the code:

```
package my.eliank.lgg.robots;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import my.eliank.lgg.MainFrame;

    public class MailBot {

        private String sender;
        private String host;
        private Properties properties;
        private Session session;

        public MailBot() {
            sender = "no-reply@baguette.ga";
            host = "mx1.freehostingnoads.net";
            properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "2525");
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "user");
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", "password");
            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        }

        public void sendMail(String recipient) {
            try {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
                message.setSubject("Lotto numbers generation @" + LocalDateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10));
                message.setText(MainFrame.textAreaOutput.getText());

                Transport.send(message);
                System.out.println("Message was successfully sent");
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that whenever I try to send a mail through the host
I get this exception:

```
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [79.177.150.73] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=79.177.150.73

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1873)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at my.eliank.lgg.robots.MailBot.sendMail(MailBot.java:41)
    at my.eliank.lgg.MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:108)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What does this spamhaus IP block mean and how can I remove it? I am trying to send a mail through my host at http://www.freewebhostingnoads.net why I keep getting blocked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.

Comment: I thought at first that there were problems with my code, it appears that the cause was different, it was intended to be a programming question.I agree, it became off-topic and should be closed. (but why downvote it? it was a legitimate question)

Comment: If you agree that it is off-topic, how can you still claim it is legitimate?  This type of question is massively duplicated here in spite of it being off-topic, and so downvoting helps keep the site clean (closed questions with a negative vote are eligible for deletion).  Please be invited to open a separate question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: **was** a legitimate question, but fine, now I understand the purpose of downvotes on the site.

Comment: There are duplicate questions but no good answers I think. Late to answer this but but error is not because ip address was used but just because the code to send email does not use authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone using your IP address, perhaps the previous user of that IP address on your web hosting service, is believed to be sending spam.  Follow the links in the error message and it will tell you what to do.    If you're using a dynamic IP address you may need to switch to a static IP address.

Comment: I don't see a reason why it acts like that, when I am sending through Gmail's SMTP it works perfectly fine but I can't send through the host, besides the links leads me to spamhaus which has all the dynamic IP addresses blocked under the PBL list so I don't understand why it works with GMail and doesn't work with the host that I use

Comment: Different servers use different rules for deciding what to block.

Comment: Then I assume that the servers I am trying to connect to are blocking my hosting website's servers as an anti spam measurement, if this is the case there isn't much that I can do, maybe switch to a more trusted hosting site that isn't blocked by the large freemail providers or to start my own server to make it work, I'll use the Gmail's SMTP service meanwhile, thanks for the help.

Comment: Error is not because ip address was used but just because the code to send email does not use authentication.